# Is the sharepoint online Search Schema accessible via rest or jsom

Tags: spfx

Anybody know if we can access  the SPO search schema via rest or csom?
I see this old post:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b8fd86c9-8a52-404c-b54c-7dc4a5975071/how-to-get-result-sources-and-search-schema-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointsearch

is it still not doable?

Comment: I am trying to find what managed property a crwled property is mapped to, ,and perhaps add a mapping

Answer (score 1):

Direct access to search schema objects is still not possible using CSOM, JSOM and REST. In CSOM you can export and import search configuration, but this is definitely not enough.